# Removing a line from a file

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file which contains

```
defg_abcd_prod
abcd_prod
hijk_abcd_prod
```

I want to remove only abcd_prod from the file, but when i am using this

```
sed -e '/abcd_prod/d' sample.txt
```

Its removing everything from file.
What changes do i need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove lines containing *only* 'abcd_prod' use a caret to match the beginning of the line and a $ to match the end:

```
sed -e '/^abcd_prod$/d' sample.txt
```

sed accepts basic regular expressions by default. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Syntax) for more syntax.

Comment: What about the situation like abcd_prod_xyz?

Comment: Answer updated. Doh.